# Composition Pattern in Javascript with Classes but without Mixins?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, composition, es6-class

Is the following a valid strategy for implementing the composition pattern in Javascript? I want to use classes instead of constructor functions or plain objects, and I know that Mixins are not best practice. One concern is that in this approach, the methods added to `Person` objects are not attached to the prototype and therefore each require memory allocation. Thanks!

```
class Person {
  name;
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

function fly() {
  return {
    fly() {
      console.log(`${this.name} can fly!`);
    },
  };
}

function swim() {
  return {
    swim() {
      console.log(`${this.name} can swim!`);
    },
  };
}

function makeFlyingPerson(name) {
  return Object.assign(new Person(name), fly());
}

function makeSwimmingPerson(name) {
  return Object.assign(new Person(name), swim());
}
```

Comment: That's still mixins, though. You *mix* two objects together - the methods/properties of one are added to the other.

Comment: If it works the way you want it to, it's valid. That said, I don't see any reason for `fly`, `swim`, etc. to be functions, and as @VLAZ pointed out, this **is** mixins. Speaking of: *"and I know that Mixins are not best practice"* Why not? According to whom?

Comment: If your motivation to use Class syntax is to ease the brain switch between, say, Java and JavaScript, I suggest your code would be very confusing for the Java developers trying to understand this. If this is your goal, then go all the way with the Class syntax so the others can grok it easily. FWIW.

Comment: @r_zelazny ... For the provided example any mixin supporting technique only makes sense if the OP actually does not want to have every person instance feature flying and swimming behavior/traits. Otherwise `Person.prototype` was still the best place to assign such behavior to. In that case it is totally valid to enhance the prototype of an already implemented `Person` class later by mixin in the desired behavior directly into the prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...the methods added to `Person` objects are not attached to the prototype and therefore each require memory allocation

True, but it's a trivial amount, the cost of one property per method per object (to hold the function reference for the method). Properties aren't *nothing*, but they aren't large. For the avoidance of doubt: The **function** object is reused by all instances, not copied.

There's no reason for `fly` and `swim` to be functions, though (at least, none that's apparent from the question), just use the objects directly:

```
class Person {
    name;
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const flyMethods = {
    fly() {
        console.log(`${this.name} can fly!`);
    },
};

const swimMethods = {
    swim() {
        console.log(`${this.name} can swim!`);
    },
};

function makeFlyingPerson(name) {
    return Object.assign(new Person(name), flyMethods);
}

function makeSwimmingPerson(name) {
    return Object.assign(new Person(name), swimMethods);
}
```

Note that this is still using mixins, though (both your original and the above).

Unless you're going to reuse `fly`/`flyMethods` and `swim`/`swimMethods` with other classes than `Person`, though, using `extends` would seem simpler and would give you prototypical method reuse:

```
class FlyingPerson extends Person {
    fly() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

If you *are* reusing `fly`/`flyMethods`, etc., with multiple classes, another option is to have factory-building functions that create a prototype from the various sets of methods and then reuse it:

```js
class Person {
    name;
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const flyMethods = {
    fly() {
        console.log(`${this.name} can fly!`);
    },
};

const swimMethods = {
    swim() {
        console.log(`${this.name} can swim!`);
    },
};

function extendWith(cls, name, ...mixins) {
    // We use the wrapper object so that the class constructor's name is assigned from `name`
    const obj = {
        [name]: class extends cls {
        }
    };
    Object.assign(obj[name].prototype, ...mixins);
    return obj[name];
}

const FlyingPerson = extendWith(Person, "FlyingPerson", flyMethods);
const SwimmingPerson = extendWith(Person, "SwimmingPerson", swimMethods);
const FlyingSwimmingPerson = extendWith(Person, "FlyingSwimmingPerson", flyMethods, swimMethods);

const joe = new FlyingSwimmingPerson("Joe");
joe.fly();
joe.swim();

class Animal {
    name;
    type;
    constructor(name, type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

const FlyingSwimmingAnimal = extendWith(Animal, "FlyingSwimmingAnimal", flyMethods, swimMethods);

console.log(FlyingSwimmingAnimal.name); // FlyingSwimmingAnimal
const splippery = new FlyingSwimmingAnimal("Slippery");
splippery.fly();
splippery.swim();
```

Comment: I wondered about this particular point in the OP's question. Which point is more important to the OP - developer communication or cohesion/minimal coupling.

Comment: The functions make more sense if they are supposed to enhance an object, e.g., `flyer = obj => obj.fly = fly`. Which then allows for one to make `flier(person)` or even `swimmer(flier(person))` to get both. With objects only, this can be `Object.assign(person, swimMethods, flyMethods)`, of course.

Comment: @r_zelazny - My pleasure! I've added to the end of it FWIW. Happy coding!